# Embedded CSS doesn't overwrite CSS in linked stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I want to overwrite background and font color of a link.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
#abc{
    background:#ffffff; // doesn't work
    color:#008080;  // doesn't work
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php include 'inc/menum.php';?>
```

menum.php

```
<div id="divL">
<a href='abc.php' id='abc'>ABC</a>
<a href='universe.php' id='universe'>UNIVERSE</a>
<a href='strel.php' id='strel'>STREL</a>
</div>
```

index.css

```
#divL  a{
background:#008080;     // works    
color:#ffffff;  // works    
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity

Comment: Solved, thanks to everyone !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a specificity issue.

The `#divL a` selector is more specific than `#abc`.

You could easily use `#divL #abc` and that would make the embedded rule more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-color` and `:link`

```
#abc{
    background-color :#fff; 

}
#abc:link {
    color:#008080;
}
```

instead. `:link` is the appropriate subclass here. color will only change the general color of the `<div>`, eg the content that is not anchor text..

Answer (score 1):

In this case You have to use `!important`

```
#abc{
    background:#ffffff !important;
    color:#008080 !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is not required, just make the selector more specific.  Overusing `!important` leads to style sheets that can be hard to maintain, especially for complex rule sets.

Comment: +1 ...Yes, using more specific selector also method. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! you have said that `#divL a{....}` works because it is selecting more specificity by selecting parent div if you can't override by just `#abc{....}` then you could place !important at last like this

```
#abc{
    background:#ffffff !important;
    color:#008080 !important;
}
```

Even if it is not working you should try by selecting more specificity div that is you have declared that `#divL a` is works

and if anytime if selecting even parent div doesn't work then you could use body selector like this

```
body #abc{
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#008080;
}
```

---

Also one hint for you if you would like to set background color then use `background-color` than `background`

Comment: `!important` is not required, just make the selector more specific.  Overusing `!important` leads to style sheets that can be hard to maintain, especially for complex rule sets.

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` to force the browser to give this value priority

E.g. `background-color: red !important;`